# Forum for cultivating a web of educational resources

Tags: educational, forum

I'm looking for forum software which allows users to submit connections between posts, and vote on said connections. Like, if there are two posts of varying detail on a topic, users could submit the less detailed one as introductory material for the more detailed one, and vote on the connection. Likewise, the inverse connection could be made as "elaborative material" and conflicting material could be linked as such.

To allow for structured discussion of the resources the comments would need to be threaded.

Rather than having the connection-feature built in, it could alternatively be simulated if the forum allowed for pinning comments. Then you could have bots produce pinned comments like "Please post links to introductory material as a reply to this comment". Sadly, support for pinned comments seems to be somewhat of a rarity when compared to pinned topics/posts.